# does autocomplete works on multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using EasyAautocomplete on my project. I was wondering if its possible to use autocomplete from 2 different file in one single searchbox. I have tried beyond the code but it reads only one of them:

```
<script>  
 var options = {    
 url: "file1.json",
 getValue: "name",
 list: {
 match: {
 enabled: true
         }
         },
   theme: "square"
        };
 $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options);$('div.easy-autocomplete').removeAttr('style');
         var options2 = {
            url: "file2.json",
            getValue: "name",
            list: {
              match: {
              enabled: true
                }
                },
            theme: "square"
        };
 $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options2);$('div.easy-autocomplete').removeAttr('style');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you that:

- Get json files at first
- Merge them
- Use them for autocomplete

The code is like:

```
$.getJSON("file1.json", function (data1) {
    $.getJSON("file2.json", function (data2) {
        var mergedData = $.extend({}, data1, data2);

        var options = {
            data: mergedData,
            getValue: "name",
            list: {
                match: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            theme: "square"
        };
        $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options); $('div.easy-autocomplete').removeAttr('style');

    });
});
```

Comment: This is actually a really good idea but when I tried this code I do get a error in console :TypeError: $(...).easyAutocomplete is not a function .What could it be? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you include  easyAutocomplete  js file and jQuery?

Comment: yes I did in the <head> section : <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>

Comment: it appears easyAutocomplete not included. Please check its path. Don't hesitate further questions.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimince/bnghwa3x/  this is working but as soon as i change the <script> code with yours then it gives an error :(

Comment: I can't run the fiddle :(